# How to properly use Three JS WebGLRenderer's method getActiveMipmapLevel()?

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, renderer, mipmaps

I have rendered a plane using Three JS with a texture image.
I want to check the active mipmap level being used as I move the object front and back.

I am trying to fetch the active mipmap level being used to render the texture by using the method provided for WebGLRenderer called getActiveMipmapLevel().
Somehow the active mipmap level always remains 0 no matter how far I move the object front / back. I am trying to refetch and print the value in the render loop.

Any idea why?

```
var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();

var mipmapped_renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
mipmapped_renderer.setClearColor("#000000");
mipmapped_renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight);
mipmapped_renderer.autoClear = false;


var mipmapped_camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
);

mipmapped_camera.position.z = 10;


document.getElementById('left-canvas').appendChild(mipmapped_renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    mipmapped_renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    mipmapped_camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

    mipmapped_camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});

var box2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 8 );

var texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/chessboard2/chessboard_512.png' );
texture2.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture2.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture2.offset.set(0, 0);
texture2.repeat.set(2, 2);
texture2.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipmapLinearFilter;
texture2.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
texture2.needsUpdate = true;
texture2.generateMipmaps = true;
var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture2, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(box2, material2);
mesh2.scale.x = -1;
mesh2.rotation.x = 90
scene2.add(mesh2);


// post processing

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 500);
light.position.set(10, 0, 25);
scene2.add(light);


// render

var render = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    mipmapped_renderer.render(scene2, mipmapped_camera);
    document.getElementById('mipmapLevel').innerHTML = mipmapped_renderer.getActiveMipmapLevel()
}

// animation

var rotSpeed = 0.1;

function onKeyDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var keyCode = event.which;

    if (keyCode == 87) {
        mipmapped_camera.position.z -= 1;
    } else if (keyCode == 83) {
        mipmapped_camera.position.z += 1;
    } else if (keyCode == 65) {
        mesh2.rotation.y += rotSpeed;
    } else if (keyCode == 68) {
        mesh2.rotation.y -= rotSpeed;
    }

    render();
}

render();

window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false);
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work like this. However, you can set your own mipmaps (for example different 1x1 textures) and play with filtering if you want transition between them to be visible.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the current mipmap level that's being used instead?

Comment: Think of it like this: make your plane much much much larger, and render it at an angle. All of the mip level can be active depending on which pixels are rendering.

Comment: You can actually use an approach like in this example to visually debug mipmaps: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_manualmipmap

Comment: @Mugen87, thank you. Interesting way to view transitions between mipmap levels.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid `WebGLRenderer.getActiveMipmapLevel()` does not do what you expect. The method only returns the value which was previously set by [WebGLRenderer.setRenderTarget()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setRenderTarget).

Besides, `WebGLRenderer.getActiveMipmapLevel()` is only used `WebGLShadowMap` to correctly restore the internal render state when the shadow map is produced. So it is not necessarily intended for user level code.

`three.js R112`